# model first table per concrete type (TPC) inheritance saves to both tables

Tags: entity-framework

trying to implement table per concrete type using model first, but when saving the derived type, EF saves to both the base and derived tables. how do you configure EF to save the type to the correct corresponding table?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good discussion of choosing an approach here that recommends against TPC for Entity Framework: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx

**For this reason:** While the EF runtime supports TPC, the designer doesn't, and using TPC in the EF forces you to avoid associations in your base type. Because of these issues we generally discourage the use of TPC with the Entity Framework.

My best guess is that if you are writing to a base and derived tables as your problem you have tried to implement this where you have a concrete class which is extended by an additional concrete class? As per the discussion above, the simple answer is TPC will not work like this for EF (the referenced article is 2009, but I don't think this has changed).